# How to return a value without an explicit method declaration?

Tags: c++

Is it possible for a class to return a value when it is called without a method?

For instance:

```
class myClass{
    private:
        int iVal;

    public:
        setVal(const int i){ iVal = i; }
} 

myClass m;
m.setVal(3);

cout << m << endl;

// In this case, m would return 3;
```

I obviously left out a ton of stuff out but is this type of operation possible?

Comment: It is if you overload the `operator <<` for the class.

Comment: Yes, provide a `operator<<(std::ostream&, const myClass&)`.

Comment: _@JeffQ_ Do you only want to get the output right, or also statements like `int x = m + 5;`?

Comment: @songyuanyao I'd suspect that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I think the best way to describe what I mean is similar to how other classes handle this.  For instance, a string can be printed without a method so I was wondering how to implement that.

Comment: @JeffQ Added upon a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for a class to return a value when it is called without a method?

I'd suspect we have to read your question as *"to return a value when it is called without an explicit **getter** method declaration?"*

Yes, you can provide an overloaded cast operator:

```
class myClass{
    private:
        int iVal;

    public:
        void setVal(const int i){ iVal = i; }
     // vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        operator int() const {
             return iVal;
        }
};
```

See the [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfd8fe92730d68a9) please.

<sub>there are some other minor errors with your code fixed as well.</sub>

---

This allows you to use `myClass` in any context as it just were an `int` value:

```
int main()
{
    myClass m;
    m.setVal(3);

    int x = m + 5; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    std::cout << x << std::endl; // outputs 8
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8712e9c4b0bebe3d)

---

The `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T)` implementation will use this overload to automatically deduce the `myClass` cast overload for `int`.

---

As for [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550740/how-to-return-a-value-without-an-explicit-method-declaration/37551070#comment62592854_37550740):

> I think the best way to describe what I mean is similar to other classes handle this. For instance, a **string** can be printed without a method so I was wondering how to implement that.

This should look like this then:

```
class myClass{
    private:
        int iVal;
        double dVal;    
    public:
        void setVal(const int i){ iVal = i; }
        void setVal(const double d){ dVal = d; }
        operator std::string () const {
             std::ostringstream oss;
             oss << "myClass { iVal = " << iVal 
                 << ", dVal = " << dVal  
                 << " }";
             return oss.str();
        }
};
```

---

The cast operator needs to be explicitly called in that case as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    myClass m;
    m.setVal(3);
    m.setVal(3.14);

    std::cout << (std::string)m << std::endl;
              // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

[<kbd>Another Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1612782d5e0493ff)

or of course overload the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const myClass&)` operator, as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37550914/1413395).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you did not want to return a value, you want to write a value to the std::ostream where cout is a instance of this which is normally linked to your console.

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass{
    private:
        int iVal;

    public:
        void setVal(const int i){ iVal = i; }
        int getVal() const { return iVal; }
};

std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& in, const myClass& c)
{
    in << c.getVal();
    return in;
}

int main()
{

    myClass m;
    m.setVal(3);

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

But there are some points to remember:

First of all the `operator` is not a class member here. If it is not a class member, it can not access private members. For this you can make the `operator` a friend of the class or prepare a getter method as shown in the example.

If you need the `friend` variant, use it like this:

```
...
public:
void setVal(const int i){ iVal = i; }
friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& in, const myClass& c);
...

std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& in, const myClass& c)
{
    in << c.iVal;
    return in;
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the actual question:  _"Is it possible for a class to return a value when it is called without a method?"_?. Well, it's a bit fuzzy, but the essence should be clear. Overwriting the output operator doesn't really answer this, but just for the context of streamed output.

Comment: The example of OP simply shows the usage of the ostream. So I believe it is possible that the question is an xy problem. So I gave a answer which is maybe helpful to get the solution of the (maybe) underlying problem. And providing a cast operator is also providing a method... So the real answer is "No" :-)

Comment: I think OP actually meant to access the interned value without using a _getter_ method.

Comment: And I think the opposite. Should we now vote to close because "unclear what you are asking"? Sorry, not my understanding of answering questions here. And downvoting for "I think the user..." is really nice :-)

Comment: However overloading the stream output operator doesn't have anything to do with _"class to return a value"_.